# Sorted and compare to method

Tags: java

I am working on a program when Frequency class can insert words into a linked list. When a new word is inserted, it adds the word into the list. If the word exists in the list, we simply increment the value of "count" for the word.  the frequency of a word has changed, I have to move the word to correct position in the linked list. If two words have same frequency, they are sorted alphabetically.

My method counts the word and put the correct position but when the words have same frequency, it doesn't sort alphabetically. Can someone help me with sorting alphabetically if the words have the same frequency?

```
public class Node implements Comparable<Node> {

    private E key;

    private int count;

    public int compareTo(Node o) {
        // words have same frequency, they are sorted alphabetically
        if (this.count == o.count) {
            return o.key.compareTo(this.key);
        } else {
            // by number of word
            if (this.count > o.count) {
                return 1;
            }
            else {
                return -1;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

my answer

```
(alice,4),(bob,3),(cathy,2),(ethan,1),(frank,1),(david,1),
```

but it is supposed to be

```
(alice,4),(bob,3),(cathy,2),(david,1),(ethan,1),(frank,1),
```

Comment: Please post code that compiles. `E` is not defined there.

Comment: You use `this` as the left-hand comparator in every situation except `o.key.compareTo(this.key);` Instead use `this.key.compareTo(o.key);` Order matters.

Comment: Yeah, we need to know what the type of "key" is, as the implementation of its comparable is relevant to a good answer.  Compass also brings up a good point.

Answer (score 1):

@Compass has it correct in the comments. Instead of

```
return o.key.compareTo(this.key);
```

you should use

```
return this.key.compareTo(o.key);
```

Comment: What is point of writing someone else comment as answer? You have not added anything from your side.

Comment: @YoungHobbit See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments

Comment: Post an answer with the solution in the comments, and make it `Community Wiki by checking the Community Wiki box`.

Comment: @YoungHobbit Literally just did that.